# CakePHP 2.2.3: How to pass variables from one form to another

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I'm pretty new to CakePHP and I've tried searching for a question related to what I'm trying to do but I *think* it hasn't been asked so here it is:

I'm developing a student forms site for a school.  The school has their own special log in system that they want users to be able to use instead of the site having its own separate log in system.  So in my `User` view I've got my `login.ctp` file that calls `login()` from the `UserController`, the login function successfully connects to the school's log-in system and validates a user's credentials (username and password are stored in `$user_name` and `$user_pass`).

I then have the log-in function check if this is the first time a user has logged in by checking the `User` model for the username used to log in to the school's system.  If the username doesn't exist the form redirects to `register.ctp` (still `User` view) where the user is required to fill in their first name, last name and some other info which gets stored in the `User` model.  I also need this register form to store the username and password used to log into the school's system.  Once the user registers in should redirect to the `Student/forms` view and use the `StudentController`.

How do I access `$user_name` and `$user_pass` in this new form?  I don't want users to be able to input this information (it should be placed in a read-only input box).

Should I just make a function `register()` in the `UserController` that creates a new `User` to add to the database?

Sorry if this has been covered before!

Here's a pseudo-example of my code:

```
UserController:
login(){
   $user_name = $_POST['username'];
   $user_pass = $_POST['pwd'];
   $data = array('username' => $user_name, 'pwd' => $user_pass);

   if(validate($user_name, $user_pass)){
      if(!exists($user_name)){
         $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register', $data));//Passing the log in data to the register function and view
      } else {$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'forms', 'action' => 'students'));}
   } else {//display invalid credential message}
}

register(){
   AppController::loadModels(array('User'));
   $this->set($data);//Setting the data passed by login() so the register.ctp view can use it
   //grab post data from registration form
}
```

I get an error saying $data is an undefined variable though in the register function, even though I'm passing it in the redirect.  How do I do this properly?

Login view:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="hero-unit span5 centerIt">
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action'=>'login')); ?>
        <fieldset id="login">
            <h2> User Login</h2>
            <p> Please Enter your [sic] Credentials </p>
            <p>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Username: ', 'type' => 'text', 'value' =>'')); ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Password: ', 'type' => 'password')); ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('remember', array('type'=>'checkbox', 'label'=>'Remember me')); ?>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="submit pull-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Register view:

```
<div class="main-content">
<div class="hero-unit span5 centerIt">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action'=>'register')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Register New User'); ?></legend>
        <p class="subHead"> Note: This information can't be changed later, please check that your info is correct.</p>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
                    //'value' => $_POST['data']['username'],
                    'readonly' => 'readonly'));
            echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
                    //'value' => $_POST['data']['pwd'],
                    'readonly' => 'readonly'));
            echo $this->Form->input('fname', array(
                    'label' => 'First Name'));
            echo $this->Form->input('lname', array(
                    'label' => 'Last Name'));
            echo $this->Form->input('role', array(
                            'options' => array('student' => 'Student')));
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="submit pull-right">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use sessions its easy

Answer (score 0):

work on your login method the way that you are writing your method is not a good practice.
[follow this article for login](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

This is not a good practice to end you form with submit button. after  do this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('submit')); ?>


//login method
public function login() {
     $user = $this->User->findByUsername($this->request->data['User']['username']);
     if(empty($user)){
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $user['User'][''id]);
            $this->redirect method...
     }
}
```

Comment: The code I gave was pseudo-code, not my actual code.  The problem I have is I'm unable to use Cake's Auth->login() method because students are required to log in via the school's pre-existing external student account system.  This means I don't have access to their database, I can only send information to system to see if the given credentials are valid.  I require a register step because the system I'm building requires students' first and last names which we need to associate to their school accounts.

Comment: do you have their email address?, or id/ or any field that you can search the field?

Comment: Students log in with their student ID.  In the past, Students' names were attached to their ID but this was changed because of security concerns (the system could be logged in anonymously and then names and IDs collected).  So I really just need to figure out how to pass a variable from my login() function to my register() function.

Comment: do you want to do it by submit button from login page to register page? if Yes. show me what yo have in your login and register view.